# VPC and Subnets for me or user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, subnet, vpc

I am trying to hook up my mobile app to AWS RDS. I want my users to be able to access the Database from anywhere and I want to view my database in SQL Workbench. Are the VPC and Subnet for allowing me access to the database or my users?

Comment: Do you plan to grant access to RDS from your local machine? This is possible (By setting publically expose option in RDS also making sure you have placed the RDS instance in a public subnet and current Securty Groups allows external access) but comes with a security risk.

Comment: Yes is there a more secure way that I should do it?

Comment: Setup an EC2 instance (Use this as a JumpBox/Bastion Host) which can connect to the RDS and keep RDS on a private subnet. To access the Database, login to the EC2 server and do it. (Also you need to add the appropriate firewall rules by setting up the Security Group rules for the EC2 instance)

Comment: Okay great thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For security reasons and proper Mobile app architecture I would not give the mobile client direct access to the database. Just one compromised machine and your data is gone, corrupted or stolen.

1. Setup an API that the mobile client reach out for data requests.
2. Give only the API access to the Database.
3. Have the mobile client use something like [Incognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to access resources.

[Here is a reference architecture from AWS for a mobile web app.](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf)

[Also a paper on how to create a backend for a mobile application](https://d0.awsstatic.com/aws-answers/aws-mobile-app-backend.pdf)

For securely connecting to the database I would use a Software VPN and allow only your IP to connect it and then allow only connections from the Private IP of that VPN to the database. VPC design considerations [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html) . I personally use [OpenVPN](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE/ref=mkt_wir_openvpn_byol), it is free for 2 concurrent users minus ec2 time.

As far as VPC subnet design goes, the Database instance should always be placed in private subnets, the api in public subnets exposed with https. [AWS cert manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/) is free to use with ELB/ALB's.

Comment: I made some lambda functions with IAM auth in API Gateway to do inserts and reads from RDS. Gateway generates a mobile API for my client that I was going to use. Would that be efficient?

Comment: Sounds great! Good luck finishing it.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer by strongjz, I would highly recommend you put your database in a private subnet and prevent any direct connections from the internet.

To connect to it from SQL Workbench you can set up a Bastion server. This is a server that acts as a middleman between the outside internet and your private subnets. There is quite a good tutorial [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/redshift-cluster-setup-private-ip) on how to set one up. They are connecting to Redshift, however the process is exactly the same for connecting to RDS.

To help with the design of the subnet IP ranges, [VPC Designer](https://vpcdesigner.com) is a good tool for designing the different subnets.

Full disclosure, I am the creator of [VPC Designer](https://vpcdesigner.com).

Comment: Okay great I’ll have to check out the link thank you!